# Какой библиотекой можно воспроизвести две мелодии параллельно и независимо?

Tags: python

То есть, есть первая мелодия со своей громкостью, и есть вторая со своей громкостью.
и играть они могут вместе и третья может появится и ничего не нарушится, так же будут играть вместе.
Через pygame не выходит. Первая останавливается если начиет играть вторая. Пример вызова:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(dir, 'test.mp3'))
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для воспроизведения двух мелодий параллельно и независимо в Python вы можете использовать библиотеку [`pydub`](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub). Вот пример кода:

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

melody1 = AudioSegment.from_mp3('melody1.mp3')
melody2 = AudioSegment.from_mp3('melody2.mp3')

melody1 = melody1 - 10
melody2 = melody2 + 5

play(melody1)
play(melody2)
```

В этом коде мы используем `pydub` для загрузки и воспроизведения двух мелодий с разной громкостью.

Установить `pydub` можно, выполнив `pip install pydub`.

Comment: Вариант возможно хороший, но у меня не получилось его запустить, так как она требует наличия установленного приложения `ffmpeg`. Я пробовал оботись установкой библиотеки `ffmpeg`, но не помогло. Это для меня вопрос так как в дальнейшем у меня станет вопрос кроссплатформенности и тогда, прийдется скачивать и принудительно устанавливать пользователю это дополнение и прописывать путь к ней для каждой системы. Может есть решение без него. Я говорю об этом так как при запуске пишет `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe'`. Установка библиотек `ffmpeg,ffprobe` не решило проблему